# How does an oblivious Turing machine work?

Tags: computer-science, turing-machines

I am reading the book **Computational Complexity: A Modern Approach** and I am having problems understanding **oblivious Turing machines**.

An oblivious Turing machine (TM) is such a TM that the movement of its heads is entirely determined by the **length of the input**. That is, the TM is oblivious to its input. So far so good.

But one of the excercises is to prove the following theorem:

```
If a language L is decidable in time T(n) 
then there exists an oblivious TM that decides L in time O(T(n)^2).
```

It is obvious that the oblivious TM must not operate on the original input of `L` but at some *coded* version. That is, the gist of the theorem is the *coding* of a **bitstring** to an **integer** (length of the input of the oblivious TM). But if one would want to code the set of possible inputs of `L` (bitstrings) to an integer, one would  run into very high numbers fairly quickly since there are `2^n` bitstrings of length `n`.

Am I understanding the problem correctly? How do you prove the theorem?

Comment: The Hint and Approach suggested in ths Homework assinment should get yo started on the right track:http://users-cs.au.dk/arnsfelt/CT08/homework/homework1.pdf

Comment: Not sure if your understanding of the oblivious TM is correct. As I understand, it just moves heads independenly from the input, but it reads the input and could change states depending on it, so there is nothing about coding. Not sure how it would help to prove the theorem.

Comment: This understanding is incorrect: "It is obvious that the oblivious TM must not operate on the original input of L but at some coded version. ". The oblivious TM or any equivalent TM should operate on the exact same input.

Answer (score 8):

Here I suggest you read this paper. It is a rather interesting and wonderful paper that will give you a proof at a lower time bound that requested. (I think you should be able to finagle it to be O(N^2) or you could conclude that O(N*log(N)) is technically O(N^2) but following this proof directly may upset your professor. I imagine he intends for you to approach it differently.

Edit:

The original link to the paper no longer works. Here is another publicly posted one.

http://www-dev.ccs.neu.edu/home/viola/classes/papers/PippengerF-Oblivious.pdf

"Relations Among Complexity Measures" by Michael J. Fischer and Nicholas Pippenger, 1979.